# Gif in UIWebView consuming high CPU

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview, animated-gif

I'm developing a hybrid application.

In a UIWebView, I'm displaying a loading GIF like this one : [image]

This GIF, is at the bottom of my web content. This content is a kind of table, and when user scrolls-down and is about to reach the bottom of the page, I'm loading more data to display. So generally, user see this GIF when scrolling very rapidly or in case of poor connection.

When profiling my app, I've noticed that when my app is displaying a GIF, it consume about 30% CPU of the device.

Here is how I'm displaying my GIF :

```
<img src="/iphone_nc/v2.2/images/loading.gif" width="35px" height="35px" >
```

So is it normal for a smartphone to allocate so much CPU to animate a GIF, or is there a neater way to display GIF?

Comment: Are you sure the high CPU usage is because of the gif and not because of the background operation that is performed as you're loading data?

Comment: Yes, I've been profiling my app with and without this line.

Comment: Same problem with you